# Trait d'union quand le mot "non" est suivi de deux mots ?

Tags: orthographe, mots-composés, trait-d-union

Bonjour,

Je me demandais quelle était la règle concernant le trait d'union quand "non" est suivi de deux mots. Par exemple "non membres permanents" ou "non-membres permanents" ?

Je sais que dans le cas d'un seul mot, il y a un trait d'union lorsque "non" est suivi d'un nom alors qu'il n'y en a pas lorsqu'il est suivi d'un adjectif. Mais je ne suis pas sûr de la règle quand il y a deux mots.

Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La règle est la même, que l'on mette l'adjectif 'permanent' après ou pas, dans les deux cas il s'agit du nom "non-membre", donc il faut un trait d'union:

> non-membres permanents

En savoir plus sur l'emploi du "non" avec un trait d'union : http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1613

Comment: Je me suis permis d'ajouter une source qui détaille la règle et donne des exemples, j'espère que c'est OK pour vous. :)

Comment: Merci pour la source.

Answer (score 1):

Le mieux est probablement d'éviter la combinaison [non] + [nom adjectif] car si on ne met pas de tiret, on ne respecte pas la règle qui le demande, et si on le met, on obtient une expression ambiguë car il ne s'agit pas d'un vrai nom composé.

La forme :

> non-membres permanents

peut être en effet comprise comme signifiant :

> Personnes qui sont des membres mais pas tout le temps → [non] [membres permanents]

mais aussi :

> Personnes qui ne sont jamais membres → [non-membres] [permanents]

Je recommanderais donc:

> personnes qui ne sont pas membres permanents

ou le moins lourd, suggéré par Reyedy

> membres non-permanents

voire simplement

> membres non permanents...

Comment: La tournure "membres non-permanents" me semble très claire également si on souhaite mettre l'accent sur la permanence.

Comment: @Reyedy C'est vrai, avec ou sans tiret.

Answer (score -1):

Il est assez bizarre de trouver que l'usage actuel ne laisse aucune trace de « non-membre permanent » et que la seule possibilité utilisée soit la forme sans trait d'union. ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&year_end=2008&year_start=1800&corpus=19&content=non+membres+permanents%2Cnon-membres+permanents&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnon%20membres%20permanents%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cnon%20membres%20permanents%3B%2Cc0), [réf.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22non%20membres%20permanents%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr))

On se rend compte de même que dans la grande majorité des cas on n'écrit pas « non-permanent » mais « non permanent » : [réf.](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=non-membre+permanent), [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&year_end=2008&year_start=1800&corpus=19&content=non-permanent%2Cnon+permanent&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnon%20-%20permanent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnon%20permanent%3B%2Cc0).

[image]

Comment: Permanent est un adjectif.

Comment: Oui, donc pas de trait d'union a priori. Mais permanent peut aussi être un nom si je ne me trompe pas ?

Comment: @user6441253 Oui, bien sûr, mais il l'est rarement dans la suite *non* + *permanent*.